# PHP / scope - set var inside function, access outside without returning it

Tags: php, variables, scope

I feel dumb but scope gets me every time. I'm not great with PHP either. How do I set a variable inside a function, in this case `$httpcode` and then access it outside that function?

```
<?php

  function get_feed() {
    $ch       = curl_init('someurl');
    $output   = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // how to use this anywhere?
    // try / catch
    curl_close($ch);
  }

  // later down the page

  if ($httpcode == "200") {
    // do this
  }
?>
```

Comment: If you don't want to return it you can either pass it by reference into the function arguments e.g. `function get_feed(&$http_code) {` (preferred) or declare it `global` inside the function (less preferred). But really, you should return it from the function.

Comment: I agree @Nick. To return the variable gives that possibility.